# Cross referencing: zref-xr does not detect .aux file of second document

Tags: cross-referencing, zref

So I am trying to crossreference labels across two documents: `draft.tex` and `appendix.tex`. When compiling I get the following error message:

```
./draft04.tex:16: Package zref-xr Warning: File `appendix.aux' not found or    empty,(zref-xr)                labels not imported on input line 16.
```

These are the two preamples of the documents including an example of a label and a reference.

First `draft.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mla}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-user}
\zexternaldocument*{appendix}
\providecommand{\biburldatelong}{}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
...
see \ref{fig:01_examples}.
...
\end{document}
```

Then `appendix.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mla_appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-user}
\zexternaldocument*{draft04}
\providecommand{\biburldatelong}{}

\begin{document}
...
\listoffigures
\newpage

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/01introduction/card_blackOps.jpg}
    \caption{Testing the crossreference}
    \label{fig:01_examples}
\end{figure}

...
\end{document}
```

These two documents are in the same directory. I really have no idea, why the `appendix.aux` is not found, since I can open it and it does contain this line, which I thought was needed for the crossreference:

```
\newlabel{fig:01_examples}{{1}{2}{Testing the crossreference\relax }{figure.1}{}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Next time, please strip down the examples and remove packages and commands that are not necessary for the problem (e.g. packages `mla_appendix`, `wrapfig`, `graphicx`, `\includegraphics`, bibliography stuff).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I get

```
Package zref-xr Info: Label import from `appendix.aux' on input line 17.
Package zref-xr Info: Statistics for `appendix.aux':
(zref-xr)             1 LaTeX label(s) found.
```

By default the label `fig:01_examples` is imported as `zref` label and can be referenced by `\zref{fig:01_examples}` (with `zref-user`). If you want the traditional LaTeX references, you need:

```
\usepackage[...]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{toltxlabel}
\zexternaldocument*{appendix}
```

Then `\ref{fig:01_examples}` or `\zref{fig:01_examples}` can be used.

Comment: It won't work with the code above if you try using `\zref`. You have to add `\usepackage{zref-user,zref-xr}`.