# .aux file not found or empty while cross-referencing between files

Tags: xetex, cross-referencing, external-files, auxiliary-files, zref

I have an issue similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115129/cross-referencing-zref-xr-does-not-detect-aux-file-of-second-document) one. In oppose to that thread, I use xelatex. Don't know, though, if this is the issue or not. I have two files. In the first one (Characteristics.tex) I have:

```
% Language specific stuff
\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Cross-referencing stuff
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-user}
\zexternaldocument*{Names}
```

Similarly in the second one (Names.tex):

```
% Language specific stuff
\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Cross-referencing stuff
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-user}
\zexternaldocument*{Characteristics}
```

Actually, it is only second file that contains references to the first file so far. So when I compile it with xelatex I get

```
Package zref-xr Warning: File `Characteristics.aux' not found or empty
```

that results into

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

I have checked, the .aux file exists and is not empty. In case this is important, I use `\label{}` to indicate the label (only in Characteristics.tex so far) and `\ref{}`,`\zref{}` or `\nameref{}` to call the reference. These work perfect in the same file, but do not work for cross-referencing between two files. Does anyone know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Does the file exist in a directory in the tex input path? such as the current directory?

Comment: Yes, all files are in the same directory.

Comment: Are you starting xelatex in this directory? What happens if you use `\input{characteristics.aux}` in the document? Is the file found?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have just tried your suggestion and it says that the file is not found.

Comment: I have also tried to add the full path to the file name, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Well if `\input` doesn't find the aux then it is not in the current directory. Check the spelling.

Comment: Banged head in the wall. It was all about spelling! Thank you very much!

Comment: This question appears to be out of scope because it was about a user error, found by the user (with the help of a comment). 